# when I click on an input of a child component a div is shown, how can I make it one at a time or hide the others?

Tags: angular

I have a child component called: 'mycomponent' with this code:

```
import { Component,Input } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
selector: "mycomponent",
templateUrl: "./mycomponent.html"
})
export class MyComponent {
@Input() myArray: any;
bShow:boolean=false;
constructor() {
}
}

<input type="text" (click)="bShow=true" >{{myArray}}
<div style="border:1px solid red; width:200px; height:50px;" 
*ngIf="bShow==true">
 data: {{myArray}}
 <br>
 <button (click)="bShow=false">close</button>
 </div>
```

I am calling it in app.ts:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of myArray">
  <mycomponent [myArray]="item"></mycomponent>
  <br>
 </ng-container>
```

when I click on the input of mycomponent a div is displayed.

How can I make this div only show in the current component I clicked on and hide it in the others?

enter image description here

this is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nienmu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Keep track of which index in your `myArray` was selected in the parent component. Only show the div if the selected index matches the index of the current item in the loop.

Comment: @Brandon Friend, excuse the ignorance. I have put my code, can you reproduce what you say please? I do not understand you

Comment: You need a property on your parent component to hold the index of which element you select. Your `*ngIf` needs to use that value and compare it to the index of the item in the loop. This way only one of your components in the loop will display the "data" section at a time.

Comment: @Brandon excuse my ignorance again, my idea is never to hide the `input` only the` div`. but i won't always send an array with ordered numbers

Comment: Which element you want to hide is irrelevant. The same logic applies

Comment: @Brandon Really, I do not understand.. :(

Comment: I don't know what's up with the close button, but here's a very quick example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5mdbdq?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: is stranger that problem with close button

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a big fan of StackBlitz. Anyway, I hope you see the logic I explained above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare all the child components as ViewChildren in the parent component.
2. Cast the ViewChildren to a QueryList array.
3. This will allow you to iterate each of the child components.
4. Now, when one component is expanded, you can iterate all others and close them.

   `@ViewChildren(MyComponent) myComponents: QueryList<MyComponent>;`

   ```
    someMethod() {
     //Cast to array and iterate
     myComponents.toArray((c:MyComponent) => {
           c.bShow = false;
     })
   ```

   }

Even with this approach you will need some way to identify the active component. Most stuff is data driven these days, so an id or index would do the trick.

```
someMethod(id: string) {
 //Cast to array and iterate
 myComponents.toArray((c:MyComponent) => {
       c.id === id ? null : c.bShow = false;
 })
```